# Swift Core Data: Data not persisting between session. context.save() works for the session only

Tags: swift, core-data

I am facing a strange issue with CoreData. I am starting a operation to fill initial data in a table. I am starting the operation in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

```
// Creating child context
let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
context.parentContext = delegate.managedObjectContext

// Reading data from database and printing here, shows zero number of entities always

context.performBlockAndWait({
    // Performing batch delete, to remove duplicacy
})

context.performBlockAndWait({
        // Creating entities from the JSON read from App bundle
        ...
        ...

        do {
            // Saving local context
            try context.save()

            context.parentContext?.performBlockAndWait({
                do {
                    try context.parentContext?.save()

                    // Reading data from database and printing here, shows correct number of entities
                } catch {
                    printDebug("Unable to save main context: \(error)")
                }
            })
        } catch {
            printDebug("Unable to save main context: \(error)")
        }
})
// Reading data from database and printing here also, shows correct number of entities
```

I am starting this operation only from once place i.e `applicationDidBecomeActive`, and also accessing the `entity` from this `operation` only.

Any idea, what is the problem ?

Comment: do you need to support pre ios 10?  If not, I would recommend using NSPersistent​Container which does background saving and main thread reading much better than parent-child  context.

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong, would you mind adding the code that shows there are zero entities when this first runs? My guess is that the code is running correctly but a small typo or something meaning that you're being told there are zero entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was batch delete using `NSBatchDeleteRequest`. I was performing same code for **multiple type of** `NSManagedObjectContext`, and all are **sub-classes of a single** `NSManagedObjectContext`. So that might be the issue.

When I perform `fetch-all-and-delete-in-loop`, everything works fine, i.e `entities` are getting stored. But when I use `NSBatchDeleteRequest` to delete all at once, the `entities` that are inserted before the `batch-delete` operation of the next **type of** `NSManagedObjectContext` are getting deleted.

So the culprit was `NSBatchDeleteRequest`. And I don't know why ? I searched but didn't find any solution. So I will post another question regarding this issue.